# Прокрутка значений тега select скроллом

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как в данном (и в любом другом аналогичном) случае включить прокрутку значений с помощью колеса мыши при нераскрытом меню тега **select** при помощи JS, в частности, JQuery. Желательно, чтобы смена значений была закольцованной.

```
<select name="hours">
    <option value="12">12</option>
    <option value="13">13</option>
    <option value="14">14</option>
    <option value="15">15</option>
    <option value="16">16</option>
    <option value="17">17</option>
    <option value="18">18</option>
    <option selected value="19">19</option>
    <option value="20">20</option>
    <option value="21">21</option>
    <option value="22">22</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

коррекция ответа @AlexanderIgorevich
смена значений закольцована, выбор направления смены за вами, body в скроле не учавствует

```js
 $(function() {
   $('[name="hours"]').on('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     var len = this.length,
       i = this.selectedIndex;
     if (e.originalEvent.wheelDelta > 0 || e.originalEvent.detail < 0) {
       this.selectedIndex = --i == -1 ? len - 1 : i;
     } else {
       this.selectedIndex = ++i % len;
     }

   });
 })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="hours">
  <option value="12">12</option>
  <option value="13">13</option>
  <option value="14">14</option>
  <option value="15">15</option>
  <option value="16">16</option>
  <option value="17">17</option>
  <option value="18">18</option>
  <option selected value="19">19</option>
  <option value="20">20</option>
  <option value="21">21</option>
  <option value="22">22</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 4):

Предлагаю такой вариант.
Отслеживать событие прокрутки мыши и в зависимости от того, вверх или вниз крутим менять `selected` используя `next()` и `prev()` соответственно.

```
$('#select').on('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function(e) {
    if (e.originalEvent.wheelDelta > 0 || e.originalEvent.detail < 0) {
        $('#select option:selected').removeAttr("selected").prev().attr(
            'selected', 'selected');
    } else {
        $('#select option:selected').removeAttr("selected").next().attr(
            'selected', 'selected');
    }
});
```

Пример в работе: **[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kixkix/bxu1wyrg/1/)**

Правда, в данном примере вместе со списком будет прокручиваться и `body`, но можно при наведении на список "запрещать" прокрутку самого документа. Например самым банальным способом:

```
$('html, body').css({'overflow': 'hidden'});
```

Comment: FF 44.02 - не работает

Comment: Если `on('mousewheel'` заменить на `on('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll`, то работает.

Comment: @nogtea Поправил.

Comment: и если выбрать выпадающим списком, а затем крутить то не пашет